# How do i insert multiple varying values from a column in one table to another table with the corresponding foreign key referenced?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

**masterlist**

```
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Brand | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Name  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**brands**

```
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| BRAND_ID | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Brand    | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**products**

```
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| Name     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| BRAND_ID | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Hi, I am relatively new to MySQL and databases and would like to ask for a method to populate my data from table to table.

**Scenario**

After creating a foreign key on `products(Brand ID)` referenced to `brands(BRAND_ID)`, I needed to insert values from the `masterlist` table into `products`. Specifically, the values under the `Name` column which are unique, but associated to the `BRAND_ID` key in the `brands` table; providing the referencing value in the `products` table.

**My current code**

```
INSERT INTO products(Name, BRAND_ID)
VALUES
  ((SELECT Name from masterlist WHERE id = 85), 5),
  ((SELECT Name from masterlist WHERE id = 86), 5)
```

This is an example of the current solution that I'm using; I am aware that it is the worst of solutions to what I'm trying to achieve. What would a more efficient way of approaching this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the `insert ... select` syntax, like so?

```
insert into products(name, brand_id)
select name, 5 from masterlist where id in (85, 86)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping me out.
I've tried the code but it returned 
#1054 - Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'

Comment: @biendilales: your schema describes a column `id` in table `masterlist`. Do you have such column in the table?